# Как правильно запостить событие клика по рабочему столу (корневому окну)?

Tags: qt, c++

Мне нужно написать приложение, которое парсит пиксель экрана при клике по любой позиции, ОС OpenSuse.
 Есть расширенный класс корневого окна:

```
class DesktopMouseGrabber : public QDesktopWidget {
public:
    QMainWindow* main_window;
    DesktopMouseGrabber(QMainWindow *window_) : QDesktopWidget(), main_window(window_) {}
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
};
void DesktopMouseGrabber::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) { // событие клика по виджету

    QApplication::postEvent(main_window, e);
}
```

И окно:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    start = false;
    desktopWidget = QApplication::desktop();
    m_grabber = static_cast<DesktopMouseGrabber*>(desktopWidget); // тип m_grabber DesktopMouseGrabber*
    m_grabber->main_window = static_cast<MainWindow* (this); // тип m_grabber->main_window - QMainWindow*

    m = this;
    connect( ui->selectButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonSelectClick()) );
    connect( ui->startButton,  SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonStartClick ()) );
}

// Нажимаем на кнопку, сворачиваем окно, делаем чтобы виджет корневого окна захватил мышь
void MainWindow::onButtonSelectClick() {
    showMinimized();
    m_grabber->grabMouse();
}

void MainWindow::customEvent(QEvent *e) { // Обработчик события клика по корневому окну
    QMouseEvent* event = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e);
    m_grabber->releaseMouse();
    this->show();
}
}
```

Проблема: при клике мыши по рабочему столу ничего не происходит, мышь не релизится, окно не разворачивается, что я делаю неправильно?

Есть ли альтернативные методы решения вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

События мыши и клавиатуры не попадут в Qt приложение, если они адресованы не ему. То есть "хук" реализовать не получится. Но можно альтернативно.
Делаете скриншот экрана:

```
QPixmap pixmap = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->grabWindow(0);
```

Затем рисуете его на каком-нибудь вновь созданном виджете, растянутом на весь экран (лучше всего метод `showFullScreen()`) в теле его переопределённого метода `paintEvent()`:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawPixmap(rect(), pixmap, pixmap.rect());
```

Ну а далее переопределяете `mousePressEvent()` или `mouseReleaseEvent()` с тем, чтобы получить координаты того места, куда пользователь кликнет, а затем скрыть и сам виджет, временно подменивший экран.

Comment: Эхм. А если в фоновом окне бежит видео?

Comment: Если на весь экран, то конечно это решение не подойдёт, т.к. скорее всего будет некрасивый скачок при перерисовке. Если по хорошему, то надо делать отлов событий системы. Но тогда это придётся писать разный код под каждую ОС в отдельности. А так, если не претендовать на изысканность и в стандартных случаях вполне работоспособное решение.

Comment: Ну и непонятно, почему `primaryScreen` (если я правильно понял название функции). А если клик будет на втором мониторе?

Comment: У QGuiApplication имеется статический метод получения списка экранов: screens(). Ну и вроде об этом речь в вопросе не велась. Всегда можно что-то подправить по ситуации.

Comment: Я эту задачу решил при помощи парсинга ввода-вывода в linux за поток мыши отвечает файл /dev/input/mice, делая клик создавался снимок экрана.

Comment: @OlegUP Запостили бы тогда в виде ответа. Это возможно будет многим интересно.

Answer (score 0):

небольшой класс mousegrabber, в отдельном потоке считывает /dev/input/mice (в нем иногда бывают вылеты)

```
void MouseGrabber::run() {
    FILE * mice;
    mice = fopen("/dev/input/mice", "r");
    if ( !mice ) {
        qWarning() << "Couldn't open: /dev/input/mice";
        qWarning() << "Note: You must be root user";
        return ;
    }

    stop = false;
    char buff[3];
    bool left_pressed = false;
    Qt::MouseButtons mb;
    while ( 1 ) {
        if (stop) break;
        std::fread( buff, 1, 3, mice );
        if(buff[ 0 ] & 0x1 && (!buff[1] && !buff[2])) { // Означает, что пользователь кликнул(нажал и отпустил) ЛКМ
            left_pressed = true;
            qWarning() << QByteArray(buff).toHex() << endl;

        } else if (buff[0] == 0x8) {
            if ( !left_pressed )
                continue;
            emit globalClick(QCursor::pos());
            left_pressed = false;
        } else left_pressed = false;
    }
}

void MouseGrabber::onStop() {
    this->stop = true;
}
```

MainWindow получает сигнал globalClick(), считывает пиксель куда кликнули, а не всю область, далее уже с полученной информацией проделывается то, что нужно.

```
void MainWindow::onGlobalClick(QPoint pos) {
    mutex.lock();
//    ui->label->setProperty("text", QString(" X: %1, Y: %2").arg(pos.x()).arg(pos.y()));
    if (!start) { px =  pos.x(), py = pos.y(); }
    QPixmap map = QPixmap::grabWindow(this->desktopWidget->winId(), px, py, 1, 1);
    QImage  img = map.toImage();
    QRgb  color = img.pixel(0, 0);

    parsePixel(px, py, color);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```